# Rails server is not working when i try to run localhost:3000 in the browser

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am a beginner into the ROR and I am making a project on ROR. The server is working perfectly but doesn't know it stops working from yesterday.

When I am starting the server it is starting normally but if I access it in the browser by http://localhost:3000 the server stops working. If I again want to start it with `rails s` it shows that the port is used by some other process. When I run this again, the server is started but again it is not able to load the index file for me.

Running the server by `rails s` command:

```
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 5.2.4.3 application starting in development
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
*** SIGUSR2 not implemented, signal based restart unavailable!
*** SIGUSR1 not implemented, signal based restart unavailable!
*** SIGHUP not implemented, signal based logs reopening unavailable!
Puma starting in single mode...
* Version 3.12.6 (ruby 2.6.5-p114), codename: Llamas in Pajamas
* Min threads: 5, max threads: 5
* Environment: development
* Listening on tcp://localhost:3000
Use Ctrl-C to stop
```

After accessing http://localhost:3000 on the browser:

```
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 5.2.4.3 application starting in development
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
*** SIGUSR2 not implemented, signal based restart unavailable!
*** SIGUSR1 not implemented, signal based restart unavailable!
*** SIGHUP not implemented, signal based logs reopening unavailable!
Puma starting in single mode...
* Version 3.12.6 (ruby 2.6.5-p114), codename: Llamas in Pajamas
* Min threads: 5, max threads: 5
* Environment: development
* Listening on tcp://localhost:3000
Use Ctrl-C to stop
Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2020-06-03 09:54:24 +0530
   (0.3ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations"."version" FROM "schema_migrations" ORDER BY "schema_migrations"."version" ASC
Processing by MoviesController#index as HTML
  Rendering movies/index.html.erb within layouts/application
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT ?  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Movie Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "movies".* FROM "movies"
  Rendered movies/index.html.erb within layouts/application (52.3ms)
```

The server stops if I am accessing http://localhost:3000 in the browser.

`index.html.erb`:

```
<% if !user_signed_in? %>
<div class="jumbotron">
  <h1> Your Faviorite Movies Revied </h1>
  <p> Hashtag, hooodie mumblercore selfies. Authentic keffiyeh leggings kickstarter, narwhal jen shorts XOXO Vice Austin cardign. Oragnic drinking vineger freegen pickled</p>
  <p><%= link_to "Sign Up To Write A Review", new_user_registration_path, class: "btn btn-primary btn-lg" %></p>
</div>
<% end %>


<div class="row">
  <% @movies.each do |movie| %>
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <%= link_to (image_tag movie.image.url(:medium), class: 'image'), movie %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

This is the file that I want to render on the browser when I access http://localhost:3000.

> show.html.erb

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-body">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <%= image_tag @movie.image.url(:medium) %>
        <div class="table-responsive">
          <table class="table">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td><strong>Title:</strong></td>
                <td><%= @movie.title %></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                 <td><strong>Description:</strong></td>
                 <td><%= @movie.description %></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><strong>Movie length:</strong></td>
                <td><%= @movie.movie_length %></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><strong>Director:</strong></td>
                <td><%= @movie.director %></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><strong>Rating:</strong></td>
                <td><%= @movie.rating %></td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_movie_path(@movie) %> |
<%= link_to 'Back', movies_path %>
```

**I run this project on a different machine and it's working, it doesn't work only in my system**

Comment: The output looks perfectly fine. Did you have a look at the source code of the returned page in your browser? How does your layout.html.erb look like? Is there data in your database? Is a user logged in?

Comment: The log file says it rendered; there's no error. So what do you mean by "it's not able to load the file"? Maybe `user_signed_in?` is returning `true` and `@movies` is empty - so there's no visible HTML to display? Did you try inspecting the page? Did you try checking the values of the above methods/variables? Nothing about the above code appears broken, based on the information you have provided.

Comment: _"the server stops"_ – I see no indication that the server stopped. To eliminate browser or rendering issues: what does `curl http://localhost:3000` return?

Comment: it's working completely fine when made changes in the index.html.erb but I made some changes in show.html.erb and after that, it stops working

Comment: if I run `curl http://localhost:3000` it shows this
`curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection was reset`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was the issue of version mismatch. I accidentally update the rails version in my computer but in the gem file there was the definition of the older version so there was version mismatch and hence I was not able to open my project in `localhost:3000`.

Answer (score 0):

The behavior you describe apears to be consistent with an issue described for the ruby-installer for Windows. The [proposed solution](https://github.com/railsinstaller/railsinstaller-windows/issues/97#issuecomment-330927091) is to

> Please try using "Command Prompt with Ruby and Rails" instead of Git Bash

It apears that on Windows, you neded to make sure to use the correct command prompt to correctly load the Ruby environment.

If this doesn't work, a different solution might be to use the [Windows Subsystem for Linux on Windows 10](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/about) for your Rails app (which might also be deployed on Linux in the end).